# MySQL JOIN and MAX

Tags: php, mysql, join, max

Hi I've got a query which does what I want to by displaying reviews which are rated first then followed by reviews which have yet to be rated. However I can't seem to get it to order correctly.

What the result should look like:

```
5
4
0
0
...
```

At the moment it is doing this:

```
4
5
0
0
...
```

Here is my query

```
$sql = $db->query( "
    SELECT branch.*, MAX(review.rating) AS m
    FROM branch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN review ON branch.bid = review.bid
    WHERE branch.address2 LIKE '$query' OR branch.postcode LIKE '$query-%'
    GROUP BY branch.bid
    ORDER BY m DESC, branch.branch ASC
    LIMIT $start,$limit 
" ) or die( "Select failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error );
```

Comment: if you remove group by then i think you will get what you desire

Comment: because records are groupded first then they get ordered within their groups

Comment: If I remove group by then only 1 result shows which is not rated

Comment: i think problem is not seen here, can you put sqls on sqlfiddle

Comment: and you may have to run inner query like

SELECT branch.*, (select max(review.rating) from review where branch.bid = review.bid) as m
    FROM branch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN review ON branch.bid = review.bid
    WHERE branch.address2 LIKE '$query' OR branch.postcode LIKE '$query-%'
    GROUP BY branch.bid
    ORDER BY m DESC, branch.branch ASC
    LIMIT $start,$limit

Comment: Ok, I've never used sqlfiddle but I think this is correct:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80ce4/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-query solution by Meghraj Choudhary should work.

However, Joins are faster.  Sub-queries require additional disk accessing.  Assuming `branch.bid` is a primary key the following should be faster:

```
SELECT b1.*, b2.m FROM branch b1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT branch.bid, MAX(review.rating) AS m
FROM branch
LEFT OUTER JOIN review ON branch.bid = review.bid
WHERE branch.address2 LIKE '$query' OR branch.postcode LIKE '$query-%'
GROUP BY branch.bid
LIMIT $start,$limit
) b2 ON
b1.bid = b2.bid
ORDER BY b2.m DESC, b1.branch ASC
```

I have not tried this.  So, please try it and post back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your solution but it still gives the same result as what it was previously doing. It seems like the rated reviews are being ordered by ascending rather than descending

Comment: @Jack Willmor - not sure why that would happen! `ORDER BY b2.m DESC,` should have taken care of that.

Comment: I figured it out, it was my own error. I needed `AVG()` rather than `MAX()` since there was two ratings for the same review and they conflicted giving the wrong result. Thanks for your help, your solution seems much more efficient.